# Sending emails to registered users worldwide by 12am at users specific timezone

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I am currently working on a project and right now I need to send emails to users worldwide on different time zone exactly by 12am.
I'm using express.js for my backend server( temporally deployed my server to heroku), MongoDB for database management , alongside node-cron for scheduling the emails with nodemailer and mailgun. Pls guys any Ideas on how my registered users can all receive their emails exactly by 12am at their different time zone.

my code base

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer"); 
const mg = require("nodemailer-mailgun-transport");
const handlebars = require("handlebars");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
let cron = require("node-cron");
const { User } = require("../models/user");
const verses = require("kjv/json/verses-1769.json");
const store = require("store2");
const { bible_books } = require("./data");
const _ = require("lodash");


async function getUsersEmail() {
  const users = await User.find().sort("email").select("email");
    return users;
}

module.exports = async function () {
   
              const emailTemplateSource = fs.readFileSync(
                path.join(__dirname, "../views/template.hbs"),
                "utf8"
              );

              const mailgunAuth = {
                auth: {
                  api_key: process.env.mailgun_apikey,
                  domain: process.env.mailgun_domain,
                },
              };

              const smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(mg(mailgunAuth));

              const template = handlebars.compile(emailTemplateSource);

             

           
                cron.schedule('0 0 * * *', async function () {
                    console.log("running task every day at 12:00 am");
                (await getUsersEmail()).map(async function (value) {
                  const bible_book = _.sampleSize(bible_books, 1);
                  store("bible", bible_book[0]);
                  let verse = store("bible");
                  let bible_passage = verse;
                  let bible_text = verses[bible_passage];
                  await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                    value?._id,
                    {
                      bible: {
                        verse: bible_passage,
                        text: bible_text,
                      },
                    },
                    { new: true }
                  );

                  const htmlToSend = template({
                    verse: bible_passage,
                    text: bible_text,
                    imageUrl:
                      "https://myimage.com/logo.png",
                    redirectUrl: "https://mywebsite.org/",
                    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
                  });

                  const mailOptions = {
                    from: "from@sender.org",
                    to: value?.email,
                    subject: "Mail subject",
                    html: htmlToSend,
                  };

                  smtpTransport.sendMail(
                    mailOptions,
                    function (error, response) {
                      if (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                      } else {
                        console.log(`Successfully sent email to ${mailOptions.to}.`);
                      }
                    }
                  );
                });
              });

}
```

Comment: You will need to store their timezone as well. And then for each timezone you will need to create a cron  which will mail only those users belonging to the timezone.

Comment: I am having issues retrieving each users time zone value stored in the database when the map function is wrapped inside of the cron job

Comment: This is a different question. You should ask a seperate question with the relevant code and exactly where you face the issue so that more people can see your question and answer it.

Comment: No bro still the same code like the one above no difference

Comment: The question you asked here is how to send emails to people from different timezones and not some error because of map function. Now you have a different problem so post another question with different title and what you would like to do(your expected format of data etc). Commenting here won't do any good as your visibility is restricted to this post. And don't edit this question because someone else might have the same problem as you, so if you edit then all comments received until now would not make sense.

Comment: I get you bro but, pls do checkout the new question [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72374357/having-issues-getting-users-time-zone